# how to restore the page URL in Jquery Mobile?

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, jquery-mobile, pushstate

I'm using nested pages in Jquery Mobile:

Looks like this:

```
// wrap page
<div data-role="page" id="wrap">
     // panel
     <div data-role="panel" data-id="popover">
         // nested pages
         <div data-role="page" id="nested1"></div>
         <div data-role="page" id="nested2"></div>
     </div>
</div>
```

On transitions, I'm switching *$.mobile.pageContainers* to load nested pages into panels vs. loading into the body (default JQM) like this:

```
$.mobile.changePage( page-to-be-loaded, {
          // previous page in panel
          fromPage:from,         
          // update the URL with the nested page hash    
          changeHash:hashChange,     
          // target panel
          pageContainer: $('div:jqmData(id="popover")')
          });
```

This all works as expected = when I load a nested page inside a panel, the URL updates to

```
http://some.com#nested1/2/3...
```

My **problem** is in "cleaning up" the URL, when I'm leaving the wrap page and going to a new JQM page altogether

In this case the URL is stuck at the last nested page, when I need to tell JQM I'm actually still on the wrap-page (no matter what nested page is still in the URL).

**Question:**
So I'm looking for a way to update the URL to it's correct value or a good way of setting the page paramaters to "factory-default" so JQM never knows I did any panel transitions on my nested page.

I have tried:

```
// 1. location hash - doesn't work

   window.location.hash = ""


// 2. ReplaceState - breaks on non-push-state browsers

   // on pageinit store defaults
   var $myState = {};   
   $myState.title = document.title;
   $myState.url = location.protocol + '//' + location.host + location.pathname;

  page.data("rememberState", $myState )

  // before leaving the wrap page
  var rem = $('#wrap.ui-page-active').data("rememberState");
  if (rem && typeof rem != 'undefined') {   
     history.replaceState('null',rem.title,rem.url);
     }

// 3. Reload the page when hiding the panel - crashes my browser :-)

   $.mobile.changePage('#wrap', {
                  allowSamePageTransition: true, 
                  changeHash:true,
                  transition:none 
                  });
```

Since I'm well off the JQM-path, I'm just looking for hints. Thanks for any pointer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it like this:

When the user first enters the site, I'm grabbing the number of history entries:

```
$windowHistoryAtInit = window.history.length
```

Say, there are 27 entries in the history, I would only want a new entry to be made when the user leaves page A and goes to page B, so all nested transitions inside pageA should not count towards the window.history total.

When the user is leaving the page, I re-check.

```
$(document).on('pagebeforehide', '#pageA', function(e, data) {
   // get number of history entries based on nested transitions
   var distance = window.history.length-self.options.$windowHistoryAtInit
   // go back distance
   window.history.go(-distance);     
   });
```

In my setup, going back the distance does not trigger actual JQM-transitions, so I'm merely taking the browser back to where it started when the user entered the site and then proceed with going from PageA to PageB.

I will probably have to tweak this by subtracting -50 from the counter, because I think it does not go above 50 entries. This way when entering with window.history.length 50, the counter starts "fresh" at 0.

Answer (score 0):

This is more of an approach answer rather than showing code but its from doing it the stupid way first and then learning from it.

The problem is you are not doing this as prescribed by the platform. You should not use the platform if you are doing it rogue it like this. You should take your nested pages and remove them. Its a bad idea. It was not programmed for that behavior. Just create 3 pages living on the same file. Then actually read the docs on how to use a multi-page app. I've done several Mobile apps and have gone through choosing bad ideas with jQuery Mobile. If you just go with the framework and know its limitations, all is smooth.

How are you going to upgrade this as jQuery Mobile is upgraded? You will be creating strange quirks going off the path. Its just not a good idea.

Comment: yeah, not really an answer :-) But since it eventually should become a JQM multi-column plugin, I will have to keep looking for a way. I think I'm getting closer to what I was looking for. On initiating my plugin, I'm grabbing window.history.length, counting entries as I'm going through my popover and when I'm closing I hope I can go back the difference between length@init and currentlength. Let's see.

Comment: Oh, you are writing a plugin. That makes sense at least.

Comment: LoL - should have mentioned this I guess :-)